# Search through filled cells in visual basic

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a beginner at using visual basic, and I've run into a little problem. What I want to do is take an excel spreadsheet and search through a specific column in order to find a name, then grab everything in that row in order to transfer it over to another sheet. I've got everything running except that I run into an endless loop for a reason I do not understand.

```
'set up a for loop that increments through all sheets in the workbook
For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
'set up a temp page to work with the current page
    Set tem = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)
    'increment through all the rows that have data in them
        For Each rng In tem.Rows
        'if the data matches what was searched for, copy it into another worksheet
            If tem.Cells(ct, 4) = SForm.Text Then
                sr.Cells(spot, 1) = tem.Cells(ct, 1)
                sr.Cells(spot, 2) = tem.Cells(ct, 2)
                sr.Cells(spot, 3) = tem.Cells(ct, 3)
                sr.Cells(spot, 4) = tem.Cells(ct, 4)
                sr.Cells(spot, 5) = tem.Cells(ct, 5)
                sr.Cells(spot, 6) = tem.Cells(ct, 6)
                sr.Cells(spot, 7) = tem.Cells(ct, 7)
                sr.Cells(spot, 8) = tem.Cells(ct, 8)
                sr.Cells(spot, 9) = tem.Cells(ct, 9)
                sr.Cells(spot, 10) = tem.Cells(ct, 10)
                sr.Cells(spot, 11) = tem.Cells(ct, 11)
                sr.Cells(spot, 12) = tem.Cells(ct, 12)

                'increment the placeholder for the new sheet
                spot = spot + 1
            End If
            'increase ct to keep track of where in the worksheet it is
            ct = ct + 1
        Next rng
        'reset ct for the next worksheet
        ct = 1
Next i
```

The Specific issue I run into, is an overflow because ct is an int and maxes out. which tells me I have an endless loop on my hands.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You are iterating over 1 million times per sheet, this is going to take a while.  Plus you do not need `ct`.  instead use `rng.row` in its place.

Comment: In [this link](http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=112:find-method-in-excel-vba-find-multiple-occurrences-find-method-to-vlookup-find-date&catid=79&Itemid=475) look at **Example - finding multiple occurrences of a value in a range.**. It will serve you greatly here. Also, you don't have an endless loop. The code is written to to check **every row** in the worksheet, regardless of whether there is data there. So once the row becomes greater than ~38,562 (don't have exact number of hand) the `Integer` variable can no longer hold it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over 1 million times per sheet, this is going to take a while.  Find the last cell in column D and only iterate through those rows

Plus you do not need ct. instead use rng.row in its place.

Then combine the whole value assignation into one line.

```
For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
'set up a temp page to work with the current page
Set tem = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)
'increment through all the rows that have data in them

    For Each rng In tem.Range("D1", tem.Cells(tem.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp))
    'if the data matches what was searched for, copy it into another worksheet
        If rng.Value = SForm.Text Then
            sr.Range(sr.Cells(spot, 1), sr.Cells(spot, 12)).Value = tem.Range(tem.Cells(rng.Row, 1), tem.Cells(rng.Row, 12)).Value
            'increment the placeholder for the new sheet
            spot = spot + 1
        End If
    Next rng
Next i
```

To make it even quicker look into dropping the whole range into an array and output into another array to minimize the interaction between the sheets and vba.

Comment: I ran through the program again using your suggestions, and it seems like it has an issue copying over the data. Would the method you use have any issues if one of the cells in either range was blank? and if so, is there a work around to this? I'm getting a "method range of object "_worksheet" failed" error. I assume that implies it is finding something that it either can't copy, or it can't copy to a specific location.

Comment: @Rejera nope sorry, my error.  I forgot to qualify the Cells() to the proper parentage.  See edit, you may need to refresh the screen.

Comment: Right, Right. I should have seen that. Works like a charm now. Thank you.